# bash / find : looking for the flles located in the above directories

Tags: bash, find

The following script tries to search the files matching the pattern and copy them to the current directory.

```
# pattern to search
lig="lig*"
output=$(pwd)
# find in anywhere and copy to the current dir
find -maxdepth 1 ../../ -name "${lig}*.png" -exec cp "{}" ${output}  \;
```

In my situation I need to look for the `$lig` somewhere above the current dir, which is

```
/home/user/Bureau/Analyse/BCL_MDtest_haddock2/Analysis
```

and the `lig*` files are located in

```
/home/user/Bureau/Analyse/BCL_MDtest_haddock2/!plots
```

How could I define the search space for `find` above the current folder (reverse to the max-dep) since I am not considering all enclosed sub-folders from the current directory?

Comment: `paths must precede expression` means that you have to flip the order of your arguments. Use `find ../../ -maxdepth 1 …`. Also note that `lig="lig*"` and `"${lig}*.png"` makes `lig**.png`

Comment: ah yes, you are right ! ;-)

Comment: I edited abit my question since I am looking for an alternative to current sollution which technically works but could not be a universal

Comment: I rolled back your edit, since the error message you are actually asking about no longer makes sense without the error you removed. Feel free to update your question to ask about a _single specific_ problem, but then take care to edit out the parts which no longer make sense.

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking. Why are you specifying max-depth if you want to look in subdirectories? If you _only_ want to examine subdirectories, try min-depth; or specify the directories directly with `../*/` (or is that `../../*/`?  It's not clear from your question, either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How could I define the search space for find above the current folder (reverse to the max-dep)

`find` can only search a directory tree that is rooted at a given starting point. It cannot go upwards from there. Your attempt to then provide a sufficiently high root (such as `../../`), and traverse from there down to the current directory (using a corresponding `-maxdepth 2`) would necessitate the active exclusion of all the undesired sibling paths that happen to share that root as a common ancestor, which is unnecessarily inefficient and not worth the effort, imo.

Instead, if you just want to copy over some files from some upper directories, why not do it directly with one crafted `cp` command? Errors related to directories not containing files with that pattern could be avoided, if needed, by setting shell options: `shopt -s nullglob` (unset again with `-u`).

```bash
cp {..,../..}/lig*.png ./
#   ..                      first directory as one source directory
#      ../..                second directory as another source directory
#             lig*.png      filename pattern in the source directories
#                      ./   current directory as the target directory
```

If this is too limiting for your use-case (the static number of parent directories, having to list all intermediate directories, command length restrictions, etc.) and/or you want more control over how each file is processed, you could also script it by dynamically first looping over the successive parent directories, then over their individual files matching, and processing them one by one:

```bash
pattern="lig*.png"
updirs=2

intodir="$PWD"
while [[ $((--updirs)) -ge 0 ]]; do
  cd ..
  for file in $pattern; do
    [[ -e "./$file" ]] && cp "./$file" "$intodir"
  done
done
# cd "$intodir" # if you need to come back within the script
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I really understand the use case, but for the "universal" part I think you  might wanna consider using the `dirname` command. It basically returns the directory (parent in this case) of a path.
For example, you could do `find "$(dirname $PWD)"`... which basically searches from the parent directory.

Comment: Switching to an absolute path instead of a relative one hardly makes any difference here. The `dirname` call just costs you an unnecessary external process.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment

> I am looking for an alternative to current sollution which technically
> works but could not be a universal

In my scenario, `$(dirname "$(pwd)")` is used to get the parent directory of the current directory dynamically and `-path` is then used to search for files matching the pattern (`${lig}*.png`) in any subdirectory that matches the pattern `*/`, which means any directory above the current directory!

let me show you how :

```
#pattern to search
lig="lig*"
output=$(pwd)

#find in directories above the current directory and copy to the current directory
find "$(dirname "$(pwd)")" -path "*/${lig}*.png" -exec cp "{}" "${output}" \;
```